# @font-face isn't working on my github io

Tags: font-face, github-pages

I'd appreciate if someone would take a look at my website and my files and see why my font face wouldn't be working. When I open my file locally, it works just fine, but on the github pages, it isn't.

Here is the files: 
https://github.com/BrookeMo/StarWarsRPG

And here is the live version of the site:
https://brookemo.github.io/StarWarsRPG/

Comment: You're referencing `./Fonts` - where is that?

Comment: in my css folder. it goes assets/css/fonts